# How to delete FOSUser. Symfony2

Tags: sql, symfony, fosuserbundle

I try delete user. But I got an error message.

```
    <many-to-one field="parent" target-entity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-all/>
        </cascade>
    </many-to-one>
```

ERROR Message

`Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ..`.

How can I delete user?

Comment: What is the whole error? it says where the problem is normally between which other entity

Comment: Have you modified some entity in SonataAdminBundle? If yes, paste the code.